# How to prohibit/workaround recursive rights on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, access-rights, google-drive-shared-drive

Let's say you have the following structure:

```
- Folder A
-- Folder A.A
-- Folder A.B
-- Folder A.C
- Folder B
-- Folder B.A
-- Folder B.B
-- Folder B.C
```

and three users, let's call them User 1, 2 and 3.

I want to grant all users access to Folder A and B so they get the structure and i don't have to grant rights to all subfolders manually. However, i want only user 3 to have access to folder A.C.

To make it clear, user 1 and 2 should be able to read this folders:

```
- Folder A
-- Folder A.A
-- Folder A.B
- Folder B
-- Folder B.A
-- Folder B.B
-- Folder B.C
```

User 3 however should be able to read the following structure:

```
- Folder A
-- Folder A.A
-- Folder A.B
-- Folder A.C
- Folder B
-- Folder B.A
-- Folder B.B
-- Folder B.C
```

If i set the rights accordingly and then remove user 1 and 2 from Folder A.C, they are still able to see it. As soon as the open the folder, GDrive displays the user again in the access list of A.C. I am assuming this is the case because the have rights to access the parent folder.

Is there any workaround for my needs?

Comment: You can start by checking the [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions). You'll use 
[Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) to grant permissions to users to a certain file.

Comment: @noogui: Sure thing i would use Permissions.Create to grant permissions, but my question is rather how i can prohibit users to re-grant permissions to themselves on files they shouldn't have access to. (like in the scenario described) i would be fine to solve this with a manual step via the GDrive GUI